# How do I enable aggregate CSS and JavaScript in Drupal 8 through drush commands?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

In Drupal 8 how do I use Drush to enable CSS and JavaScript aggregation (under admin->configuration->development->performance->bandwidth optimization)?

Answer (score 2):

To set configuration in Drupal 8 through drush the command name changed:

```
drush config-set <config-name> <key> <value>
```

The CSS and JS settings are part of `system.performance`

```
drush config-set system.performance css.preprocess TRUE
drush config-set system.performance js.preprocess TRUE
```

Warning: Lots of sites enable or disable those using the settings.php or settings.local.php files, and these drush commands will *not* override those values.

[More about config set.](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/163993/drupal8-what-is-the-new-drush-command-that-replaces-drush-variable-set)

Comment: should be `drush config-set system.performance css.preprocess 1` 

and 

`drush config-set system.performance js.preprocess 1`